# Convert csv file into Multi tab xls (excel) file using perl

Tags: excel, perl, csv

I am using perl module WriteExcel to convert a | delimited text file into xls file, I am using below code to do so

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

# Create a new workbook and add a worksheet
my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($filename);
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet("Colorful Example");

open(FH,"<$my_path/source_file.txt")
   or die "Cannot open file: $!\n";
my ($x,$y) = (0,0);
while (<FH>){
   chomp;
   my @list = split /\t/,$_;
   foreach my $c (@list){
      $worksheet->write($x, $y++, $c);
   }
   $x++; $y=0;
}
close(FH);
$workbook->close();     # Close Workbook
```

By this code i can convert the file into single tab excel. 
I am wondering how can i **convert the text file into multi tab xls (excel file having multiple worksheets) file when number of rows exceed 65000.**

Comment: yes by using same package.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding your worksheet with this line.

```
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet("Colorful Example");
```

What you need to do is check in your loop where you process lines if you have exceeded the line limit, and if you did, replace the worksheet handle.

```
$worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet('foo') if $rows > 65_000;
```

Comment: in your code $rows is getting calculated from where??

Comment: That would be your `$x` I guess. Remember to always chose good descriptive variable names so you don't get confused.